# Is the previous object destroyed when the variable holding it gets assigned a new one using a copy constructor?

Tags: c++, destructor

Take a look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    private:
        int _x;
        int _id;
        static int count;
    public:
        A(int x) : _x(x) {
            this->_id = A::count++;
            cout << "Object with id "      << this->_id
                 << " has been created."   << endl;
        }
        ~A() {
            cout << "Object with id "      << this->_id
                 << " has been destroyed." << endl;
        }

        int get_x(void) {
            return this->_x;
        }

        A add(A& object) {
            A tmp(this->_x + object._x);
            return tmp;
        }
};

int A::count = 1;

int main(void) { 
    A object_1(13);
    A object_2(5);
    A object_3(12);

    object_3 = object_1.add(object_2);

    cout << object_3.get_x() << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output from the program:

```
Object with id 1 has been created.
Object with id 2 has been created.
Object with id 3 has been created.
Object with id 4 has been created.
Object with id 4 has been destroyed.
18
Object with id 4 has been destroyed.
Object with id 2 has been destroyed.
Object with id 1 has been destroyed.
```

I don't understand what happened to Object with id 3? It definitely was created, but I see no line telling me that it was ever destroyed. Can you please tell me what's going on here?

As an aside question, why is it that when I use `return 0`, the destructors work fine, but when I use `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)` I don't see `Object with # has been destroyed` printed on the screen as though the destructors are never called.

Comment: Your output is incomplete, since you didn't track the copy constructor.  Look at the `add` function and what it returns.

Comment: `exit()` doesn't call destructors. By definition. If you want destructors called, you return from main. That's just how the language works.

Comment: @MikhailR. See this with [no optimizations](http://rextester.com/SLKNSX2722).  Now see this with [optimizations enabled](http://rextester.com/EXTKL92760). Note the differing output, one invokes the copy constructor, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the previous object destroyed when the variable holding it gets assigned a new one using a copy constructor?

This question is moot because it is not possible to do so.

When you run

```
object_a = object_b;
```

this calls the *assignment operator* (not the copy constructor). It does not create or destroy any objects (unless your assignment operator does that).

In this case you haven't defined an assignment operator, so the default one is used, which overwrites `object_3`'s ID with the other object's ID (which is 4). So when `object_3` is destroyed it prints "Object with id 4 has been destroyed".

Comment: Okay, all that makes perfect sense, but isn't it the default copy constructor's job to copy all the stuff from Object #4 to Object #3? I thought when you use the assignment operator with objects, the default copy constructor kicks in and does the process of copying?

Comment: @MikhailR. -- The copy constructor can be removed by the compiler.  So as of today's C++ standard, you cannot predict when or how many times the copy constructor will be invoked.

Comment: @MikhailR. The copy constructor copies all the stuff and the assignment operator also copies all the stuff, but they are not the same.